# Can't read application.yml using @Configuration.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here's my `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  port: 8089

schedulers:
  identity:
    origin: http://localhost:7189
    client-id: 72612d8e-b78e-446c-9397-354435696ec3
    secret: 173a7f6a-8263-11e7-bb31-be2e44b06b34
    username: integrationCLient
    password: P@ssword
    token-cache-backoff: 5
    default-token-cache-ttl: 5
    endpoints:
      validateToken: /v3/api/validateToken
      issueToken: /v3/api/oauth/v2/token
    httpClient:
      numOfRetries: 3
      backOffInMillis: 5
  couchbase:
    bootstrapHost: localhost
    bucket: default
    connectionTimeout: 1000
```

I am trying to read the file into my Spring Boot application. Here's the relevant code:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "schedulers")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CouchbaseConfig {

  CouchbaseContext couchbaseContext = new CouchbaseContext();

  @Bean
  public Bucket bucket() {
    System.out.println("askfjaslkfjafa" + couchbaseContext.getBootstrapHost());    //throws NPE
    CouchbaseEnvironment env =
        DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .connectTimeout(Long.parseLong(couchbaseContext.getConnectionTimeout()))
            .build();
    Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, couchbaseContext.getBootstrapHost());
    return cluster.openBucket(couchbaseContext.getBucket());
  }
}
```

Here's my `CouchbaseContext.java` file:

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CouchbaseContext {
    private String bootstrapHost;
    private String bucket;
    private String connectionTimeout;
}
```

I am getting `NPE` while trying to access the `couchbaseContext` object in `CouchbaseConfig.java`. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think the indentation of your yaml file is incorrect. Is `couchbase` supposed to be nested under `scheduler`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Let me verify it online once.

Comment: @NicholasK It is a valid yml, just checked.

Comment: Wrap `CouchbaseContext couchbaseContext = new CouchbaseContext();` in a method and annotate it with `@Bean`. Looks like `spring` isn't aware of the object since you defined it *explicitly*

Comment: @NicholasK Did:   
  [at]Bean
  public CouchbaseContext couchbaseContext() {
    CouchbaseContext couchbaseContext = new CouchbaseContext();
    return couchbaseContext;
  }

No success still.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Not sure if this will make a difference but can you just return `new CouchbaseContext()` instead of the reference? Also try to give it a name to rule out wrong bean name. Do you see any errors during start-up?

Comment: Actually, I did what you just told and it didn't work. No errors during startup as well, except that it fails to create a CouchBase bean. I guess I'll debug a bit more thoroughly.

Comment: @NicholasK The answer to the question works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
    CouchbaseContext.class
})
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public Bucket bucket(CouchbaseContext couchbaseContext) { ... }
}
```

moreover you can remove @Configuration in CouchbaseContext

Comment: you are welcome, please find more information here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html